# joiner by regex

Tags: sql, join

i have issue about join between 2 tables, there are 3 levels key in master table and 5 levels key in detail table.

here is example, detail table:

```
p1     p2      p3      p4       p5
1      2       0       0        0
1      3       2       0        0
1      3       2       4        0
1      3       4       2        5
```

etc, the rules for detail table is if there is zero number in p3/p4/p5 then the next field is always zero. the key could be combined each field, example for first row to next are 12, 132, 1324, 13425.

master table:

```
q1     q2      q3
1      2       0
1      3       2
1      2       3
```

etc, the rules for master table is same as detail table. the key could be combined like 12, 132, 123.

the main issue is we must look for key in master table, if the key combined is 12 then it could be join to detail table with key 12, 132, 1324, 13425 (key contain 12). if the key combined is 132 then it could be join to detail with key 132, 1324, 13425 (key contain 134), if the key is 142 then it could be join to detail with key 142, 124, 1243 (key contain 142). noted that p1 = q1.

Answer (score 0):

*i just wanted to leave a comment*
**I'm sorry if I misunderstood** 
if you sort by merging p1/p2/p3/p4/p5 so q1/q2/q3

detail table column:
00012
00123
01234
12345

master table column:
012
123
123

it comes in this view

it is enough if you now find the destail  column -> master column string.